# Get countries under a continent using geonames API

Tags: java, geonames

I am new in Geonames API. I need to write java code using Geonames API to print countries under a continent.

Example:

Europe is a continent and Italy is one of the countries under this continent. So I want to print all the countries under Europe continent.

I am able to get all continent names as You can see my code here. Now I want to get all countries for one of the continents. I just dont know what should be in the toponymSearchCriteria or how can i find it !

Code:

```
package geonames;

import org.geonames.Toponym;
import org.geonames.ToponymSearchCriteria;
import org.geonames.ToponymSearchResult;
import org.geonames.WebService;

public class app {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        WebService.setGeoNamesServer("api.geonames.org");
        WebService.setUserName("shajedulislam");
        ToponymSearchCriteria searchCriteria = new ToponymSearchCriteria();
        searchCriteria.setFeatureCode("CONT");
        ToponymSearchResult searchResult = WebService.search(searchCriteria);
        for (Toponym toponym : searchResult.getToponyms()) {
            System.out.println(toponym.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Africa
Asia
Europe
North America
South America
Oceania
Antarctica
```

Comment: “I don't know how to write the code for it.”, meaning you don’t know java or you don’t know the API? The API looks well documented to me. Anyway you need to be more specific about your issue or this question will probably be closed

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear. I have updated my question. Please check it !

Answer (score 0):

You need uri like this 
`http://api.geonames.org/search?name_startsWith=Berlin&featureClass=P&type=json&username=shajedulislam&maxRows=100&lang=EN&continentCode=EU` 
There're we have `featureClass=P` and `continentCode=EU`.
With that query params we will find cities which name starts with Berlin in Europe continent. 
Here is [documentation](https://www.geonames.org/export/geonames-search.html)